# Fourier Transform definitions for operator

Tags: operator-theory, definition, fourier-transform, adjoint-operators

I am following the convention of FT for operators, normalized to a length scale $L$, whereby
$$
a_{k}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}\int dx\,e^{-ikx}a(x)\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1) \\
a^{\dagger}_{k}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}\int dx\,e^{-ikx}a^{\dagger}(x)\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(2)
$$
where the sign of the phase factor is not flipped upon conjugation of $a_{k}$ (see https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.4729 Table 1). How can I show that
$$
a^{\dagger}(x)\equiv[a^{\dagger}(-x)]\,\,?\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(3)
$$
Here's my attempt: I take the IFT of the operators such that
$$
a(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}\int dk\,e^{ikx}a_{k}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(4) \\
a^{\dagger}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}\int dk\,e^{ikx}a_{k}^{\dagger}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(5)
$$
If I look at Eq.(4), I first take $x\rightarrow -x$
$$
a(-x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}\int dk\,e^{-ikx}a_{k}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(6)
$$
and taking the conjugate of Eq.(6)
$$
[a(-x)]^{\dagger}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}\int dk\,e^{-ikx}a_{k}^{\dagger}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(7)
$$
where I've followed the convention that taking the dagger does not change the phase in the integral. Clearly, Eq.(5) is not the same as Eq.(7), but I feel like I'm missing something and that they should be a constitutive relation relating $x\rightarrow-x$ to the dagger of the operators.

Thank you.

Comment: Taking the conjugate of Eq.(6) sends $-i$ to $i$, so the RHS becomes $a^\dagger(x)$

Comment: @SolubleFish Yes, but if I'm following the convention that taking the dagger of the operator doesn't change the phase, then it wouldn't match. So how do I resolve the discrepancy in the convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with some operators $a_k$ and their adjoints $a_k$ (in the usual sense, where conjugation is anti-linear, so flips the phases). Then you *define* their respective Fourier transforms $a(x)$ and $a^\dagger(x)$ by equations $(1)$ and $(2)$. Here, since you are defining new operators, you have all the freedom to chose the sign of the phases (in other words, you can chose whether you take the Fourier transform or its inverse).

However, with the choice we are making here, the adjoint of equation $(1)$ is not $(2)$, but rather :
\begin{align}
a_k &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}\int \text dx e^{-ikx}a(x) \tag{1} \\
a_k^\dagger &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}\int \text dx e^{ikx}(a(x))^\dagger \tag{$1^\dagger$}
\end{align}

In other words, because of the choices we made, $a^\dagger(x)$ is not the adjoint of $a(x)$. Changing $x\to -x$ in the RHS, we get :
$$a_k^\dagger = \frac1{\sqrt L} \int \text dx e^{-ikx} (a(-x))^\dagger$$
and comparing with $(2)$ we see that $a^\dagger(x) = (a(-x))^\dagger$.

As I point out, your calculations go wrong between equations $(6)$ and $(7)$. You are taking a hermitian adjoint. There is only one convention here, and it flips phases.

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, I start with some operator $a_k$ and its adjoint $a_{k}^{\dagger}$ in the usual sense (conjugation flips the phase). But then when I define the Fourier transform of $a_k$ (like how I did with equation (1) with $e^{-ikx}$), the conjugation $a_k^{\dagger}$ is thought of like a new operator which follows the same FT definition (namely, the same phase $e^{-ikx}$). Is this the right way to think about it?

Comment: Also, at the part where you said "comparing with $(2)$ we see that $a^{\dagger}(x) = (a(-x))^{\dagger}$", that equation does not have the same phase sign as in $(2)$. Is it valid to compare them or is it a typo? Just clarifying

Comment: (1.) This is the way I think about it. (2.) I messed up the signs. I corrected it, and now the sign matches in the Fourier transform for $a^\dagger(x)$ and $(a(-x))^\dagger$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. This was helpful.